# SQL server improve performance of joining a large and small table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to join two tables:

Table1: (900 million rows (106 GB). And, id1, id2, id3, id4 are **clustered primary key**, houseType is string)

```
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| Id1 | id2 | id3 | id4        |  val1  |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  15 | 697 | houseType1 | 75.396 |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  15 | 697 | houseType2 | 20.97  |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  15 | 805 | houseType1 | 112.99 |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  15 | 805 | houseType2 | 53.67  |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  27 | 697 | houseType1 | 67.28  |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
| ac  |  27 | 697 | houseType2 | 55.12  |
+-----+-----+-----+------------+--------+
```

Table 2 is very small with 150 rows. And, val1, val2 are **clustered primary key.**

```
+------+------+---------+
| val1 | val2 | factor1 |
+------+------+---------+
| 0    | 10   | 0.82    |
+------+------+---------+
| 10   | 20   | 0.77    |
+------+------+---------+
| 20   | 30   | 0.15    |
+------+------+---------+
```

**What I need :**

For every "val1" in table1, it should be found which range [val1, val2] in table2 it belongs to and its associated "factor1" in table2 should be returned from table2, which will be used for further aggregate calculation.

example of my query:

```
 Select a.id1, a.id2, a.id3, a.id4, 
         max(case when a.val1 >= b.val1 and a.val1 < b.val2 then  b.factor1 * a.val1
                else null
            end ) as result
 From Table1 as a,
      Table2 as b
 Group by  a.id1, a.id2, a.id3, a.id4
```

For example, a row :

```
   ac ,  15, 697, houseType2, 20.97 in table1
   0.15 should be returned from table2 because 20.97 in range [20, 30] in table2.
```

**There is no join action in the query because I do not know how to use join here. I just need to lookup the factors for val1 in table2.**

In SQL server, it runs very slow with more than 3 hours.

I also got :

```
   Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.
```

Could anyone help me about this ?

thanks

Comment: Look at the execution plans. Add indexes and ensure your `STATISTICS` are correct. Not performance-related: but avoid useless aliasing (especially cryptic, 1-letter aliases without a good reason) and never use `SELECT *` in a query not ran by a human.

Comment: you have no join condition to limit the amount...so its 900 million * 150...135 billion...is that really our goal...why would you need 135 billion records at once

Comment: The message "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation." is because you are producing NULLs inside of a MAX() function. Any value is larger than a NULL so many NULLs will not appear in the final result.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: SQL server 2008

Comment: @Ctznkane525,       
There is no join action in the query because I do not know how to use join here.

Comment: Create a non-clustered index on col Table1.val1 should help. May take very long time though.

Answer (score 1):

This should reduce your recordset:

```
Select a.id1, a.id2, a.id3, a.id4, 
         b.factor1 * a.val1 as result
 From Table1 a inner join
      Table2 b on a.val1 >= b.val1 and a.val1 < b.val2
```

This way, you will only get a single record from b for each record from a.  This is at least a start to improve your performance problem.

No need for MAX because you are joining to get a single record.

Comment: removed the group by...not needed

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to express this as a subquery or lateral join:

```
Select a.id1, a.id2, a.id3, a.id4, b.factor1 * a.val1 as result
From Table1 a cross apply
     (select b.*
      from Table2 b
      where a.val1 >= b.val1 and a.val1 < b.val2 
     ) b;
```

The aggregation is unnecessary because the four keys constitute the primary key.